# Re-routing DNS queries with iptables properly without resolv.conf

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, nat, tcpdump

I run a custom DNS service on 127.0.0.1:53 and I dont just want all queries to go through it, I also want only that service to respond back. Which is where  the problem arises. My NAT iptables setup:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:53
```

Here tcpdump of me, pinging `ya.ru`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -nnSXvv -i any udp
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
18:34:15.974227 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20601, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 51)
    192.168.0.6.54387 > 127.0.0.1.53: [bad udp cksum 0x3fe0 -> 0x2c11!] 58964+ A? ya.ru. (23)
    <data here>
18:34:15.974457 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26083, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 604)
    192.168.0.6.56172 > 77.66.84.233.443: [bad udp cksum 0x6533 -> 0x48f0!] UDP, length 576
    <data here>
18:34:16.028783 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 7923, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 204)
    77.66.84.233.443 > 192.168.0.6.56172: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 176
    <data here>
18:34:16.029127 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12032, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 78)
    1.1.1.1.53 > 192.168.0.6.54387: [bad udp cksum 0xc2fb -> 0xc42e!] 58964 q: A? ya.ru. 1/0/1 ya.ru. A 87.250.250.242 ar: . OPT UDPsize=1252 (50)
    <data here>
18:34:16.075993 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 20662, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 73)
    192.168.0.6.38972 > 127.0.0.1.53: [bad udp cksum 0x3ff6 -> 0x7be2!] 32011+ PTR? 242.250.250.87.in-addr.arpa. (45)
    <data here>
18:34:16.076448 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 26142, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 604)
    192.168.0.6.53415 > 77.66.84.233.443: [bad udp cksum 0x6533 -> 0xf1ca!] UDP, length 576
    <data here>
18:34:16.186718 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 7930, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 268)
    77.66.84.233.443 > 192.168.0.6.53415: [udp sum ok] UDP, length 240
    <data here>
18:34:16.187096 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 12081, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 103)
    1.1.1.1.53 > 192.168.0.6.38972: [bad udp cksum 0xc314 -> 0xfa7e!] 32011 q: PTR? 242.250.250.87.in-addr.arpa. 1/0/1 242.250.250.87.in-addr.arpa. PTR ya.ru. ar: . OPT UDPsize=1252 (75)
    <data here>
```

1) process with local port 54387 sends request and it is being redirected to 127.0.0.1:53 as expected
2) local custom DNS service sends request to remote DNS server
3) remote server responds back
4) ??? the original process with local port 54387 receives response from  1.1.1.1:53 ???
5+) repeat for PTR

What and why happened here and how can this be avoided without editing resolv? It wouldnt be a big issue overall but the DNS queries from custom service are encrypted while response from 1.1.1.1:53 isnt.

For reference, current resolv.conf updated via DHCP lease:

```
1.1.1.1
8.8.8.8
```

I don't have the ability to edit it because original question was intended for Android 9+, which simply [does not have a place where you can just set DNS and be happee](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205606/how-to-configure-dns-properly-while-two-lans-are-running/205740#205740). I managed to repro the same situation on my **CentOS8** setup so the question should **applicable**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request in point 1) above is seen AFTER DNAT in one of the prerouting chains took place. This is why you see destination address of 127.0.0.1 instead of the ORIGNAL destination address of 1.1.1.1. This packets and up at your resolver and then you seem to proceed with DNS over HTTPS.

When the response back from your local resolver is sent back to the requestor it ALSO goes through NAT. This NAT will ensure the SOURCE address of the response is the ORIGINAL DESTINATION address of the request. This is why you see 1.1.1.1 as the source address in point 4) above.

Basically NAT is taking place at two places:

1. It modifies the OUTGOING packet according to the rule you supplied.
2. It also modifies the INCOMING packet to revert the modification above and to ensure return packet is properly matched to correct socket at the "originating" node.

Comment: I might have properly failed to convey what is my issue. It is the point 4), not 1-3, i have no issues with 1-3 and I understand why it happened and this is exactly what I want. My issue is that there is "plain-text" dns response with bare requested domain name that comes from 1.1.1.1 which shouldnt be there (otherwise the whole point if securing queries and responses is moot).

Comment: You properly conveyed your issue :). Please re-read my answer. As I (hopefullly) described the response is coming from LOCAL resolver. The point is that the request has been DNATted (from 1.1.1.1 to 127.0.0.1) and as a result of this - the response has to and has been SNATted (from 127.0.0.1 to 1.1.1.1). You can verify this by attaching wireshark to the outgoing interface - both request and response should NOT show there. They will only show on `lo` interface as the result of NAT.

Comment: Okay, thanks,I think now it starts to make sense to me. So the process sends packet with DestIP in header which gets rewritten by the NAT rule and then it is forwarded to 127.0.0.1. Same thing happens for inbound which is why I see response as from 1.1.1.1.  
Is there anyway for me to see the process of redirection happening with some tools, basically same log but with some annotations/pointers that stuff was redirected?

Comment: You can use `conntrack -E --dst-nat` for events related to, or `conntrack -L --dst-nat` to dump the state of those altered connections.